# Starts with Selector with $(this) target

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got a set of form fields based on output from a database. When the page is loaded the fields are populated with the value from the database.

Basically what I want to do is control the .show() .hide() of the div's based on the inputs value. If it's greater > 0 than the div should show.

Each input has a class "event" so I'm using the Starts With Selector to target the inputs and handle the if() statement, however I'm running into problems on the targeting of the individual elements after that fact.

```
            if ($('input[class^="event"]').val() > 0) {
                $(this).parent().show();
            }
```

My basic ($('input[class^="event"]').val() > 0) works if I put an alert(); on it, but as I said, the targeting of the elements after that isn't work for me.

**EDIT - As Requested, the HTML**

```
<div class="formbox Open sept25_morning"><input name="newsletter" value='#POPULATED_FROM_DB' class="event"/><strong>Good 'ol Hockey Game<br />
    9:00 am - 11:00 am</strong><br />&nbsp;</div>

<div class="formbox Open sept25_morning"><input name="newsletter" value='#POPULATED_FROM_DB' class="event"/><strong>Event #2<br />
    9:00 am - 11:00 am</strong><br />&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: would help if you could post your HTML

Comment: could we see some of the HTML

Comment: Alright added the HTML. The basic $(this).parent.show(); is working for me on another section of the site. It's just specifically the targeting with the starts with selector that's got me stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends what context you are running your if statement, you could try something like this if it is on page load:

```
$('input[class^="event"]').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() > 0) {
        $(this).parent().show();
    }
});
```

[**Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpeZG/)

Comment: Yeah, for what he wants, he's going to have to run the `each()` function. Here's a simple example on JSBin: http://jsbin.com/imazo3/edit

Comment: @RussellUresti - +1 For beating me to the example :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to select all the inputs with a class which starts with `"event"` and then show their parent class if the value is greater than zero?

You could use `.each` like in Scoobler's answer, or `.filter` like below:

```
$('input[class^="event"]')
    .filter(function () {
        return $(this).val() > 0;
    })
    .parent()
    .show()
;
```

Comment: A custom filter like this is an interesting idea; it even turns out to be slightly faster than using `each()`: http://jsperf.com/each-vs-filter

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$("input.event").each(function(){
    if ($(this).val()> 0) {
        $(this).closest("div").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `val` method will only return the value of the first input. To check every single input, you'll have to use an `each` loop:

```
$('input[class^="event"]').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() > 0) {
        $this.parent().show();
    }
});
```

Also, for what it's worth, I could have sworn there was a jQuery selector based on an input's value, but I couldn't find anything like that in the docs. There's probably a plugin or something.

**EDIT**

Also, based on your HTML, it doesn't look like you need that complicated selector. You could probably just use `input.event` or something.